# смена chroot, не могу разобраться

Tags: linux, chroot

Ситуация следующая, эмулируя прошивку роутера, как обычно задал корень

```
chroot . ./qemu-mips-static /bin/busybox
```

Все скрипты работали хорошо, но суть не в этом. Теперь не могу поменять обратно корневой каталог, система упорно не может найти `/bin/bash` это и понятно. Все сторонние программы считают что корень находится в папке с прошивкой и необходимые библиотеки пытаются найти там.

```
chroot . ./bin/bash
```

ничего не даёт.
Как вернуть обратно.

Comment: `exit` (или *ctrl+d*)

Comment: Проблема не решилась. `file /bin/ip` например говорит что это mips файл. Система по прежнему считает рутовый каталог в каталоге с прошивкой.

Comment: судя по всему, вы запустили несколько оболочек одну за другой. завершайте их работу, пока не вернётесь «на самый верх».

Comment: А каким образом можно посмотреть текущий рутовый каталог? На будущее если что?

Comment: ну, как обычно: `ls /`.  но я, возможно не понял, что именно вы подразумевали под словосочетанием «рутовый каталог». если «какой каталог вы указали первым параметром программе *chroot*?», так изнутри изолированного окружения, которое создаёт эта программа, «наружу ничего не видно». в этом и заключается смысл изоляции процессов.